# Datatables Simple Join Query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, datatables

I am putting together a simple join query using Datatables Editor however am getting errors which I don't understand. My code is below:

HTML

```
            <!-- Actions -->
            <div id="divActions" class="tab-pane fade">
                <ul class="nav nav-list">
                    <!-- Actions Tab Header -->
                    <legend id="lgdActions">Actions</legend>
                    <table id="tblActions" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
             Actions Datagrid
            $('#tblActions').DataTable({
                dom: "Tfrtip",
                lengthChange: false,
                bAutoWidth: false,
                jQueryUI: true,
                bProcessing: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "dataGridQuery.php",
                    data: { "gridNumber": 2 },
                    type: 'POST'
                },
                columns: [
                    { title: "Action ID", data: "tblActions.actionID", width: "10%" },
                    { title: "Time", data: "tblActions.actionTime" },
                    { title: "Action Taken", data: "tblActions.actionTaken" },
                    { title: "User", data: "tblUsers.userID" }
                ]
                tableTools: {
                    sRowSelect: "os",
                    aButtons: [
                        { sExtends: "editor_create", editor: editor1 },
                        { sExtends: "editor_edit",   editor: editor1 },
                        { sExtends: "editor_remove", editor: editor1 }
                    ]
                }
            });
```

PHP

```
            // Obtain Action Grid
            if(isset($_GET['gridNumber']) && $_GET['gridNumber']==2){ 
            //
            $data = Editor::inst( $db, 'tblActions' )
                ->field(
                    Field::inst( 'tblActions.actionID' ),
                    Field::inst( 'tblActions.actionTime' ),
                    Field::inst( 'tblActions.actionTaken' ),
                    Field::inst( 'tblActions.actionUserID' ),
                    Field::inst( 'tblUsers.userID' )
                )
                ->leftJoin( 'tblUsers', 'tblUsers.userID', '=', 'tblActions.actionUserID' )
                ->process($_POST)
                ->data();
            //
            if ( ! isset($_POST['action']) ) {
                // Get a list of sites for the `select` list
                $data['tblUsers'] = $db
                    ->selectDistinct( 'tblUsers', 'userID as value, userID as label' )
                    ->fetchAll();
            }
            // Echo 
            echo json_encode( $data );
            }
```

The errors I receive when running this code are:

- Errors {"error":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown
  column 'tblActions.id' in 'field
  list'","data":[],"tblUsers":[{"value":"1","label":"1"},{"value":"2","label":"2"}]}
- DataTables warning: table id=tblActions - Invalid JSON response. For
  more information about this error, please see
  http://datatables.net/tn/1.

This code was from a sample provide when downloading the Editor v1.3.1.  I am somewhat familiar with the plug-in however find it perplexing when such an error occurs.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a field for id in the tblActions.id table?

Comment: The primary key for the tblActions is actionID.  There is no field "id".

Comment: It looks as though you likely have to change your primary key somewhere.  By default it seems as though it is looking for "id" as the primary key. http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/19199/custom-primary-key

Comment: adpro-I will be reviewing this after finishing other work and provide a follow up.  Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the name of the primary key.

I think if you add the following somewhere.

```
 "idSrc": "actionID",
```

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/19199/custom-primary-key

This also may work

```
        $data = Editor::inst( $db, 'tblActions' )
            ->pkey( 'actionID' )
```